# How to get "start of the year/month" in NodaTime?

Tags: .net, datetime, nodatime

I know there is `DateTimeZone.AtStartOfDay` method, but are there analogs to get start of the year/month? I know the easiest way is to hardcode those to "first day of X and 30 seconds" (which I did `LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, DateTimeKind.Utc));`), but I think that's far from best practice

Comment: what do you expect to get from a `AtStartOfYear/Month` ?

Comment: @WiiMaxx to get a corresponding date and time value. month is especially interesting, since it has a higher probability to be affected by DST than start of the year

Comment: Why do you not first set your `ZonedDateTime` to first day of year/month using the properties like (DayOfYear)(http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/html/P_NodaTime_ZonedDateTime_DayOfYear.htm) and then call `DateTimeZone.AtStartOfDay`?

Comment: Can you give more details about what you're trying to achieve? `AtStartOfDay` is used when converting from a `LocalDate` to a `ZonedDateTime` - is that what you're doing as well, or is it something else? (A sample of what you're trying to achieve, including the types involved, would be very useful.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I need to calculate a period between a given ZonedDateTime and start of the year. The results of the computation are then used to store info in the database

Comment: The start of the year in that time zone? I'd just create a `new LocalDate(year, 1, 1)` and then call `AtStartOfDay` as normal. (Please edit your question to clarify it, with an example.)

Comment: @JonSkeet edited the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You certainly don't need to go via `DateTime` - but to get the start of a year in a particular time zone, I'd just use:

```
var startOfYear = zone.AtStartOfDay(new LocalDate(year, 1, 1));
```

Note that this will be useful to get the *duration* between a `ZonedDateTime` and the start of the year. For a *period* (e.g. 5 months, 2 days, 3 hours) you'd need to just use `LocalDateTime`, which won't take the time zone into account. (Period arithmetic just becomes weird in the face of time zones...)

To get a `LocalDateTime` you can just use:

```
var startOfYear = new LocalDate(year, 1, 1).AtMidnight();
```

... although there's no guarantee that that date/time occurred in any particular time zone (or only occurred once).

Comment: But to use it in `Period.Between(start, now, ...)` calls, should I do `startOfYear.LocalDateTime` as documentation suggests?

Comment: @chester89: No, you might as well just create a LocalDateTime for the start of the year. This kind of thing is exactly why I asked you for more details in the question. It would really help if you gave examples of input and expected output.

Answer (score 6):

It's also possible to use [date adjusters](https://nodatime.org/2.2.x/api/NodaTime.DateAdjusters.html) to solve the problem. For the start of the month it would be:

```
LocalDateTime now = new LocalDateTime(2014, 6, 27, 7, 14, 25);
LocalDateTime startOfMonth = now.With(DateAdjusters.StartOfMonth);
Console.WriteLine(startOfMonth); // 2014-06-01T07:14:25
```

There is no native adjuster for the start of the year though, but we can combine:

```
LocalDateTime now = new LocalDateTime(2014, 6, 27, 7, 14, 25);
LocalDateTime startOfMonth = now.With(DateAdjusters.Month(1)).With(DateAdjusters.StartOfMonth);
Console.WriteLine(startOfMonth); // 1/1/14 7:14:25 AM
```